# When doing memory analysis in Java, TreeMap is found inside the object

Tags: java, object, memory

I'm new to memory analysis in Java.

I have a custom class named **ExecutionReportMessage**, the object of which cost me 25k memory:

[image]

When I look into the object in Memory Analysis in Eclipse, I found that there's a **TreeMap** structure inside, which accounts for the most size of the whole object.

Here's my question:

1. Where does the **TreeMap** come from? I don't have **TreeMap** structure in the definition of the class.
2. I'd like to reduce the size of the object as less as possible. Any possible way to do that?

Comment: It might just be from some sort of library that you use in your project, not directly from your own written code.

Comment: Do you have a `Map` anywhere?  That could just be the concrete implementation going into that `Map` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It looks like it is inside the `quickfix.fix42.ExecutionReport` object..??

UPDATE: It is in fact inside the `quickfix.fix42.ExecutionReport`, which by inheritance extends the `quickfix.FieldMap` class, which has two `TreeMaps`

2) Remove the ExecutionReport from your exception and just store the fields you need from it.

Comment: Yes, it's a custom quickfix.fix42.ExecutionReport object. But I've seen the implementation of ExecutionReport, no TreeMap is defined inside.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with quickfix, but it appears that the class quickfix.fix42.ExecutionReport may hold a lot of fields internally, and why not use a TreeMap for that? I looked at the 1.5.3 source, but it appears that all messages are code generated? Can you point me to the source code from which you state your proposition?

Comment: I think you need to follow the guide on the website, to execute a task in a ant file to generate ExecutionReport.java

Comment: Alright, I did your work for you. ExecutionReport extends quickfix.fix42.Message, which extends quickfix.Message, which extends quickfix.FieldMap, which has a pair of TreeMaps.. So you receive them by inheritance..!

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen add that to your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, `TreeMap`s are used internally by [QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixj.org/) (in this case, by the `ExecutionReport` class). To get a better understanding of what's going on, you'd have to look at the QuickFIX source code.

Comment: I have the source codes but can't find any TreeMap in ExecutionReport class